# How do you display items from a list in a message box?

Tags: c#, list, struct, messagebox

I am working on a project that needs to display a list of people that have above average income. The source data is a `List<IncomeData>` (`id` is the unique id for the person):

```
public struct IncomeData
{
    public string id;
    public double household;
    public income;
}

public double belowAverage = 0, total, belowAveragePercent;

IncomeData surveyStruct;
List<IncomeData> surveyList = new List<IncomeData>();
List<string> aboveAverage = new List<string>();
```

Here is how I determine if a person has above average income. If a person has above average income, I add the `id` and `income` from the temporary instance of the `surveyStruct` to the above average list of string values:

```
//Determine poverty.
if (surveyStruct.income - 3480 * surveyStruct.household <= 6730)
{
    belowAverage += 1;
}
else if (surveyStruct.income - 3480 * surveyStruct.household >= 6730)
{
    aboveAverage.Add(surveyStruct.id);
    aboveAverage.Add(surveyStruct.income.ToString());
}
```

And here is the code that displays the desired information in a message box. (The `aboveAverage` list is added in here, too.)

```
private void reportsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Display reports 1, 2, and 3.
    MessageBox.Show("Your Entry:\nID Code: " + surveyStruct.id +
       "\nHousehold: " + surveyStruct.household.ToString() +
       " people\nIncome: " + surveyStruct.income.ToString("C") +
       "\n\nPeople Above Average:\n" + aboveAverage +
       "\n\nAnd " + belowAveragePercent + "% of people are below average.");
    }
```

**Now, here's the problem:** Instead of a seeing a list of values in the message box, I am seeing `System.Collections.Generic.List```1[System.String]` where the IDs and incomes of the above average people should be. Can somebody please tell me what I am doing wrong and how I can display a list values in a message box?

Answer (score 1):

At the end of your question you ask: **How I can display a `List<IncomeData>` in a message box?**

So, the core of your question is converting your list of values to a string so that you can pass that string as an argument to `MessageBox.Show()`.

The **LINQ** Extension Method [Enumerable.Aggregate()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548651%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) offers an ideal solution for this problem. Say your `List<IncomeData>` looks something like this (I've omitted the `household` field for brevity):

```cs
var incomes = new List<IncomeData>() {
    new IncomeData("abc0123", 15500),
    new IncomeData("def4567", 12300),
    new IncomeData("ghi8901", 17100)
};
```

The following LINQ query will convert that `List<IncomeData>` into a `string`:

```cs
string message = incomes.
    Select(inc => inc.ToString()).
    Aggregate((buffer, next) => buffer + "\n" + next.ToString());
```

---

To eliminate the need to call `Select()`, you can instead use the two-argument version of [Enumerable.Aggregate()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549218%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This approach also allows you to specify a heading as the seed value for your accumulator:

```cs
string message2 = incomes.
    Aggregate(
        "Income data per person:",
        (buffer, next) => buffer + "\n" + next.ToString());
```

That is equivalent to the following where the argument types have been made explicit:

```
string message = incomes.
    Aggregate<IncomeData, string>(
        "Income data per person:",
        (string buffer, IncomeData next) => buffer + "\n" + next.ToString());
```

---

See the following (and [online demo](http://rextester.com/FDOIQ36513)) for a complete working example preceded by its expected output.

**Expected Output**

```
Income data per person:
Id: abc0123, Income:15500
Id: def4567, Income:12300
Id: ghi8901, Income:17100
```

**Demonstration Program**

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace LinqAggregateDemo
{
    public class Program
    {

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {            
            var incomes = new List<IncomeData>() {
                new IncomeData("abc0123", 15500),
                new IncomeData("def4567", 12300),
                new IncomeData("ghi8901", 17100)
            };

            string message = incomes.
                Select(inc => inc.ToString()).
                Aggregate((buffer, next) => buffer + "\n" + next.ToString());

            Console.WriteLine("Income data per person:\n" + message);
        }

        public struct IncomeData
        {
            public readonly string Id;
            public readonly int Income;

            public IncomeData(string id, int income)
            {
                this.Id = id;
                this.Income = income;
            }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return String.Format(
                    "Id: {0}, Income:{1}",
                    this.Id,
                    this.Income);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

StringBuilder is one choice:

```
    StringBuilder aboveAverage = new StringBuilder();

    //Determine poverty.
     if (surveyStruct.income - 3480 * surveyStruct.household <= 6730)
    {
        belowAverage += 1;
    }
    else if (surveyStruct.income - 3480 * surveyStruct.household >= 6730)
    {
        aboveAverage.Append(string.Format("id: %s, income: %s\n",
                surveyStruct.id, surveyStruct.income.ToString());
    }
```

And you will need a ToString() for the string builder, like this:

```
    MessageBox.Show("Your Entry:\nID Code: " + surveyStruct.id + "\nHousehold: " + surveyStruct.household.ToString() + " people\nIncome: " + surveyStruct.income.ToString("C") + "\n\nPeople Above Average:\n" + aboveAverage.ToString() + "\n\nAnd " + belowAveragePercent + "% of people are below average.");
```

You could do it with join if you leave aboveAverage as a list, like this:

```
 string.Join(aboveAverage,Environment.NewLine);
```

In your current code -- but that would not look so nice.

You could also do it with Linq, you want to see that?

Ok, here is a sexy one line version: (all questions should have a one line linq answer):

(the using and indent don't count, they are just there to make the code more readable!)

```
using NL = Environment.NewLine;
    
string indent = "    ";

MessageBox.Show(
  "Your Entry:" + NL +
  "ID Code: " + surveyStruct.id +  NL +
  "Household: " + surveyStruct.household.ToString() + " people" + NL +
  "Income: " + surveyStruct.income.ToString("C") + NL + NL +
  "People Above Average:"  + NL +
     indent + string.Join(NL+indent,
                          surveyList.Where(s => (s.income - 3480) * s.household >= 6730)
                                    .Select(s => "ID: "+s.id+" $"+s.income.ToString).ToArray()) + NL +
         "And " + (surveyList.Where(s => ((s.income - 3480) * s.household) <= 6730).Count() / surveyList.Count()) * 100 + "% of people are below average.");
```

Comment: @Hogan Would it be different if I used Linq?

Comment: @chotto-motto - It would be only one line long!!

Answer (score 0):

First, make aboveAverage a `List<IncomeData>`, and add the IncomeDatas that match into that list.

Then, you need to define a `ToString` for your custom struct, something like this:

```
public override void string ToString()
{
  return string.Format("The id is {0}, the household is {1} and the income is {2}.", id, household, income);
}
```

Then, in your MessageBox.Show call, you need to replace aboveAverage with

```
aboveAverage.Aggregate((a,b) => a.ToString() + Enviroment.NewLine + b.ToString())
```

Should make it show properly.

Sorry about the formatting,I'm on mobile.